# Rephrasing this Chinese sentence for emphasis (他和很多人在一起过, ‪但第二天他根本懒得打个电话.)

Tags: sentence-structure

My source sentence is: 他和很多人在一起过, ‪但第二天他根本懒得打个电话. The source translation is: "He had been with many people that he didn't care to call the next day."

I was wondering if I could rewrite the sentence to be something like this: 他已经和很多他‪第二天根本懒得打个电话的人在一起过。

Thanks!!! I miss bugging you guys with my questions. lol

Comment: it will become a run-on sentence

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: No. As it stands your re-write doesn't make sense in Chinese. How do you want to re-write it?

Comment: The reason I felt I wanted to change the Chinese was because, in this TV show, the English the lady was speaking was putting emphasis on his behavior and tendencies, not necessarily the acts of being with people and not calling them. She was trying to express that he's the type of person who doesn't care about people he sleeps with. And I sort of felt the Chinese sentence emphasized the acts themselves rather than emphasizing his style of person. So as an exercise, I'm trying to figure out how to keep the sentence but rewrite it to emphasize it in a way that more expresses this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

This reminds me questions of Chinese exam in China. Many questions are just like "whether a setence like XYZ can be transformed into XZY in this context". The answer is always "No". In Chinese, different form of a same sentence often comes with a totally diffrent emphasis, hence make them different in meaning.

`他和很多人在一起过-但第二天他根本懒得打个电话` is emphasized on the twist of "Had been with lots of people" and "wouldn't even give a phone call the next day",
which stress his unusual or unsatisfying attitude.

`他已经和很多他‪第二天根本懒得打个电话的人在一起过` is emphasized on the fact that he had "been with many people that wouldn't even give a phone call the next day", which stess on his behavior.

Comment: I think grammatically they are correct, but in the meaning, they have a slight difference?

Comment: Yes, actually it is quite hard to have a wrongly grammared Chinese sentence. They just have a diffrent meaning.

Comment: The reason I felt I wanted to change the Chinese was because the English the lady was saying puts emphasis on his behavior and tendencies, and I felt the original Chinese translation was perhaps making it about the acts themselves (of getting with people and not calling them back). I felt the original Chinese sentence's emphasis was not too correct, so I was trying to figure out on my own how to rewrite it to emphasize it properly.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence suggests a promiscuous, bisexual man? Is that correct? Or what is the context?

He had been with many people (whom) he didn't care to call the next day.
他曾和很多他第二天都懒得打个电话的人在一起过。

Comment: This is from a reality TV show "Selling Sunset," and it's generally about realtors. They always go into their personal lives and whatnot. In this sentence though, she was trying to say she was in a relationship with a guy who had a tendency to frequently be with a lot of different people but cared nothing about them. So, yes, definitely promiscuous and uncaring.